# ng-change="aFunction()" on select being ran twice

Tags: angularjs

I've seen other posts on Stack suggesting that this is caused by Angular being included twice, but angular.js is only included once in index.html

My select code is as follows:

```
<select id="categorySelect" ng-model="catList_" ng-options="cat.id as cat.name for cat in catList" ng-change="generateCategoryList()">
```

And whenever a dropdown is selected, generateCategoryList() is called twice in the controller, the value of $scope.catList_ is the value of the select on the first run and then when it unwantedly runs for a second time, $scope.catList_ is null

Comment: can you create an example for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x7mhjLs9/

That's not a working example as the controller calls a service upon ng-change.

Comment: Ah, as I see in your fiddle, the first thing you do in your generateCategoryList function is re-defining catList as an empty array, thus the value in your dropdown will instantly change again (triggering ng-change), calling generateCategoryList again and setting $scope.catList_ to null (since you emptied the catList array)

Comment: Thanks @Guinn. Not sure how to tackle that as I need to empty the dropdown contents as the contents shouldn't be amended, it should be replaced with the data that in the XHR request (category.get)

Comment: You could tackle it by making sure atleast the value you select in the dropdown 'remains' in the array. Thay way ng-change won't be triggered. So you could store the new data in a temporary variable, iterate through both arrays and delete/add the data appropriately. (see if old value is in new array etc)

Comment: @Guinn - That hasn't worked unfortunately (http://jsfiddle.net/96xb7wej/)

As you can see, on line 3, I update $scope.catList to be an array of ['test'] and then add the data from the XHR to it. So even though $scope.catList is never empty or undefined (except pre page load) it still runs $scope.generateCategoryList() twice, with the same values hitting the console.log (x and then null)

Comment: Yeah, because by re-assigning the array with the value 'test' in it, you still change the value, even though the new value is the same as the old value. re-assigning means deleting the old, and assigning a new! I meant you iterate through the old and new array and compare them. I'll see if i can cook up a fiddle

Comment: Looking at your fiddle though, why would you want to show subcategories of a category in the same dropdown? :o Anyway, this fiddle should do what you want without calling the function twice: http://jsfiddle.net/96xb7wej/2/